# What can I do about a large input text that can't all be fit into memory

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I have a dataset with approximately 300k samples where each sample is a text document with about 25k words.

I can load it all into memory, but I can't really use a GRU network since I just run into a memory error due to the number of parameters

I tried setting the max vocab length to 35000 and max sequence length to 2500 after which I could run a GRU network. I got a slightly good accuracy but I'm  losing 90% of my data.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to load a smaller input dataset at a time and iterate over the whole dataset, Or you could use small batch size in your training.